# XCode12 Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode12, xcode12.3

I am currently trying to make an app using XCode12 and Swift, but the default Navigation Bar height is too tall. I can't seem to find anything for XCode12 on how to change the height of the Navigation Bar, and I am very new to iOS app development.

Does anyone know how to change the height of the Navigation Bar on XCode12 programmatically?

Please let me know!

Comment: The navigation bar metrics are defined by the OS, you only can choose to use the large or small title. You have to work with what you got.

Answer (score 0):

I too had issues with the Navigation Bar. I assume you ask this question because your elements are covered by the navigation bar or there is not enough space to add everything you want without the UI getting to crammed so here are two ways to workaround this:

1. Elements may be covered by the navigation bar because you have used the `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` modifier. You can remove or alter this modifier and elements will not slide beneath the navigation bar(ex:`.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)`).
2. You can use `UIScreen.main.bounds`.(height or width) to size your elements programmatically.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! We are going to try these! However, for #2, where do you put UIScreen.main.bounds.(height or width)? I'm so sorry, I'm really new to all of XCode and Swift.

Comment: Lets say you are trying to size an Image... 
You could use UIScreen.main.bounds.width in the .frame(width:,height:) modifier.